# “list.add” does not working in class(EmployeeClass) which not having main method in C#

Tags: c#, list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public struct employee
{
    int EmpId;
    string EmpName;

    public employee(int EmpId,string EmpName)
    {
        this.EmpId = EmpId;
        this.EmpName = EmpName;
    }
}

class EmployeeClass 
{
    List<string> e = new List<string>();
    e.Add("Nitin");
    List<employee> e1 = new List<employee>();
    e1.Add(new employee(1,"prakash"));

}
```

> the name 'e.Add' does not exist in the current context
>
> the name Add does not exist in the current context

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> e = new List<string>();
        e.Add("Nitin");
        List<employee> e1 = new List<employee>();
        e1.Add(new employee(1,"prakash"));
    }
}
```

> In this list is working fine in main function but when i am trying same code in  EmployeeClass then its not working

Comment: You can't just put code inside a "Class", you need to put your code inside a method. You can declare and instantiate variables directly inside the Class scope, but you can't run code like that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put code directly into the class except for field initializers. It needs to go in a method or the constructor or a property. Here is how to do it in the constructor and read the comments inline to see how to do it in methods and property as well:

```
class EmployeeClass
{
    public EmployeeClass()
    {
        List<string> e = new List<string>();
        e.Add("Nitin");
        List<employee> e1 = new List<employee>();
        e1.Add(new employee(1, "prakash"));
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // You can put code here
    }

    public List<string> SomeProperty
    {
        get 
        { 
            // You can put code here too 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put a logic anywhere outside the methods/properties as such to execute that code it should be in a place which can be called by and the code is performed 
you need to change the structure of you employee class to this

```
class EmployeeClass
{
   List<string> e = new List<string>();
   List<employee> e1 = new List<employee>();
   public EmployeeClass()
   {
      e.Add("Nitin");
      e1.Add(new employee(1, "prakash"));
   }
}
```